# Android Long text got cut off textview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-cardview

So, I'm using cardview to for a fragment page in one of the page of my android application. I'm using the cardview to get a neat square-ish layout, but for long text, for the last paragraph it got cut off by 1 line, and also layout_marginbottom does not seem to work. What happen?

This is my fragmentpage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ifgf_logo" />

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Title 1"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Title 2"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Title 3"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Title 4"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:textColor="#626262"
                        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the screenshot
before I scroll down, and after I scroll down. The top part correctly have margin top, but the bottom part, does not seem to have any margin, and also cut off some text.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can give a little `padding` at bottom in `CardView`

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a blank view like this:

```
 <View 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="20dp" />
```

// set the height according to your requirement

Place this code into the layout (both at start and the end ) of the scroll view.

Do like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title 1"
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title 2"
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title 3"
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title 4"
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                android:textColor="#626262"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: it does not work.. the paragraph still got cut off like in the picture, only until "Aldus pagemaker" it supposed to go until Lorem Ipsum again

Comment: Well I tried the same code in my device, it is working fine. Please have a look on my code.

Comment: I tried your code, it works, but that because you don't have the cardview part. with cardview it does not work..